Trying to show a filtered list of users (with their real names, images) in a slack dropdown
In slack's single user select dropdown, you can only see all the users in the team, not specific users. What I want to do, is show a specific list of users in a channel in the dropdown, along with their pfps. Problem is, for some reason, the slack's conversation select has a filter property but the users select does not.
https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#users_select
https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#channels_select
How do I do it? The point is to show a list of filtered users in a dropdown, (which needs to have some payload/private metadata attachable to it as well) along with their images.
I tried building a custom dropdown but can't seem to fit the images in due to their restrictions.
